# laravel 4 insert one to one relationship example

Tags: insert, laravel-4, eloquent, one-to-one

Ok so I can't seem to get a insert to work with a one to one relation ship. I will start with my models:

```
Class Maintenance{
    public function taskList(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\TaskLists','maintenance_id','list_id');
    }

Class TaskLists{
    public function maintenance(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Maintenance','maintenance_id','list_id');
    }
```

ok, and my controller:

```
$log = new Maintenance();
$log->status = $status;
$log->save();
$list = TaskLists::create(array('title'=>'Maintenance Log'));
$log->taskList()->save($list);
```

now here is the error I get:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'maintenance_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `taskLists` (`title`, `maintenance_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Maintenance Log, , 2014-06-18 18:00:50, 2014-06-18 18:00:50))
```

So laravel documentation doesn't really state this is the way to insert a one to one relationship. So my question is, how do I do that? Can you provide and example.

Thanks much!

Comment: Those relation definitions are definitely wrong. What are the keys and foreign keys on the tables?

Comment: Your not passing the maintenance_id to the second query, try adding it into the data array you pass to the second save() method. `array('maintenance_id' => $log->id, 'title'=>'Maintenance Log');`

Comment: @deczo - The keys are shown above in the models.

Comment: @Jeesmusu - I thought that was the point of having eloquent manage the relationships, that it would insert the proper keys.

Comment: @JasonSpick your first relation definition says this: `maintenance_id` is foreign key on the `TasksList`s table and `list_id` is primary key of the `Maintenance` model. So once again - what are the PKs and FKs on the tables?

Comment: Alright, I did have one key in the wrong place, I have adjusted it above. It doesn't produce an error now, but it does not fill the keys.